# iptables FORWARD rule blocking return traffic

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have a VM running OpenVPN with client-to-client disabled and I need some specific forwarding rules. IP forwarding on the VM is turned on.

The OpenVPN base network is 172.30.0.0/16 and that is further subdivided into /24 subnets with their own rules.

172.30.0.0/24 should have access to all the clients. The rest should not. I have 2 subnets defined at the moment; 172.30.0.0/24 and 172.30.10.0/24.

Following the suggestion at the bottom here;
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/configuring-client-specific-rules-and-access-policies/ - I set up my rules as follows;

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -s 172.30.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

This does not work. If I add a -j LOG at the top, I can see that traffic from my client at 172.30.0.1 connects fine to the client at 172.30.10.3, but all traffic it sends BACK is blocked.

If I set the policy to ACCEPT everything works and I can connect to the client just fine, so this is not a routing problem.

How can I set this up? And why doesn't the suggestion in that OpenVPN guide work?

Comment: GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).
I’m voting to close this question because

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

which allows established connections to return. Everything works as desired now.